# IDs are not displayed after using the purify package with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, htmlpurifier

I have a Laravel website and I'm using the `stevebauman/purify` v6 package to clean and validate content on the frontend. However I have a little problem. When I have an id in an html tag, it removes it or rather it just doesn't display it.

This is what I tried so far:

1. Updated the allowed.HTML in `config/purify.php` like this

```php
'HTML.Allowed' => 'h1[id],h2[id],h3[id],h4[id],h5[id],h6[id],b,strong,blockquote,code,pre[class|id],i,em,a[href|title|id],ul,ol,li,p[style|id],br,span[id],img[width|height|alt|src|class|id]',
```

2. I also added this line to the config file:

```php
'Attr.AllowedFrameTargets' => array('_blank', '_self', '_parent', '_top', 'id'),
```

3. In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` I added the class:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->register(\Stevebauman\Purify\PurifyServiceProvider::class);
}
```

4. I also made sure to empty the cache `php artisan config:cache`

I'm displaying the content in my view like this:

```xml
{!! \Purify::clean($post->content) !!}
```

Unfortunately the IDs are not displayed on the frontend.

Comment: ``php artisan config:cache`` will cache config instead of clearing!! Call ``cache:clear`` instead.

Comment: `config:cache` does clear the cache before.

Comment: I've tried all cache clearing commands just to be sure, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Purifier disallows `id` attributes by default. You need to explicitly allow them with an additional toggle: [Attr.EnableID](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.EnableID):

> Allows the ID attribute in HTML. This is disabled by default due to the fact that without proper configuration user input can easily break the validation of a webpage by specifying an ID that is already on the surrounding HTML. If you don't mind throwing caution to the wind, enable this directive, but I strongly recommend you also consider blacklisting IDs you use ([%Attr.IDBlacklist](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.IDBlacklist)) or prefixing all user supplied IDs ([%Attr.IDPrefix](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Attr.IDPrefix)).